# Pyspark Linear forecast

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I am still new to world of Pyspark and Big data.....

My problem is related to Linear forecasting function and how to derive this data for a larger dataset in pyspark

Below is the link for data which i use for scenario value calculation

[Scenario_Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nxl7o.png)

[Scenario Data with output using return](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3xjg0.png)

Based on expected return i calculate scenario value

Example if the expected return is 3% ---> i manually identify the rows which will provide values for X & Y.....so in this case 3% will be between 1% and 5% after identifying this row manually, i calculate scenario value using formulae in excel (forecast.linear), so in this case of 3% , my scenario value computed will be -162.5

Objective is to calculate all of this within pyspark with no manual effort which was mentioned above

Let me know if you need any further details on this query

Thanks a lot in advance for the help

Note: I am using databricks for this task

Regards
Hitesh

Comment: Please give an example (code snippet) what you exactly want to do. Do you want to predict data?

Comment: Hi @JAdel, as mentioned earlier, i do this manually in excel, objective is to automate this in pyspark added new screenshot under Scenario Data with output using return !!Hope this helps

Comment: I am voting for this question to be closed, because it has nothing to do with pyspark or apache-spark-sql.  Please describe your problem and the logic more exactly on your next question. Use code snippets to reconstruct your problem.

Comment: This is very unhelpful and impolite.....i described my problem statement and how i currently do this in excel....i provided sample data also......you need to understand not everyone is expert on this platform...some are novice like me